# I need to upload media content (video or image) storage in SQL Azure to Azure BLOB Container

Tags: sql, azure, blob, azure-data-factory

Actually the information is stored in BASE64 in a varchar field. I've created a stored procedure to convert that field into varbinary. With the following code:

```
cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("[name of the column]"))', 'varbinary(MAX)')
```

The result is shown in the following picture:

[image]

The media is storage (SQL Azure) in varbinary, after storing the media content as file in the  BLOB Container, I cannot be able to render the media to watch its content if I donwload it in my local computer. Even If I try to open the file with a local editor I can see the same value as the image shows above.
All the convertion process is running in Azure SQL Server and call it using a ADF process.

What is the best approach to load those media using Azure Data Factory? Is it another way to save BASE64 to image from SQL to Blob storage in AZURE?
Thanks

Comment: From what format of image have you converted it to Base64?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert Varbinary data type back to Base 64 and then save it to Blob.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804415/convert-image-data-type-into-base64-and-base64-into-image-data-type) and see which method you would like to implement out of an answer by *Manoj Choudhari* or *Divya Agarwal*.